# Is it possible to show the command prompt window when launching a batch file from the task scheduler?

Tags: batch-file

As my title states, I am wondering if it is possible to show the command prompt window (at least temporarily) to ensure that my batch file is indeed being executed as scheduled. The batch file runs without errors when I run it manually.

The batch file resides on Windows Server 2008 R2 Standard, x64 and I have service pack 1 installed. Let me know if more info required.

Thanks much!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you are trying to capture output, I like to dump to a log file.  Put this as your program to execute in Task Scheduler:

```
myscript.bat >> error.log
```

If you REALLY want it to stay open, you could do -

```
cmd /k myscript.bat
```

Comment: Your second option is exactly what I needed. Thank you.

Comment: I tried this but it does not work when you select the security option 'Run whether user is logged on or not'. The cmd window is still hidden.

Answer (score 4):

Alternatively, if you'd like to have the batch essentially idle for some time, an old trick is to make it ping localhost for, say, 10 seconds (or however long you want).
To do that, add "ping localhost -n 10". This way your batch will finish and terminate, but give you 10 seconds to see that it did, in fact, start.

Answer (score 3):

In a .bat file, the PAUSE command makes it appear until you press a key. While more than a second, it gives you a chance to see it if you leave the machine for a while.

Comment: Well, at least on my test batch. Will investigate further and report back.

Comment: How can you stop exe file? I am running exe file from a console app.